# How to postmessage HTMLIFrameElement?

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I'm having issue passing `HTMLIFrameElement` object from parent site to iframe (located on a different domain) using `postMessage` method.

This is my code that I already tried:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('myHTMLIFrameElement');
frame = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(frame));
event.source.postMessage(frame, "*");
```

Unfortunately, `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify` does not seem to be the right way of handling `HTMLIFrameElement` object. Can you please advise how to pass through `HTMLIFrameElement` object correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing DOM elements as JSON does not do anything useful as far as I know.
Since `postMessage()` is part of the window object, you could try using the window object of the frame, which is found under the `contentWindow` property of the iframe.

So you could try something like:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('myHTMLIFrameElement');
frame.contentWindow.postMessage( "stuffYouWantToSendToTheIframe", '*' );
```

And then in the script inside the iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function( event ) {
   // handle message
});
```

Comment: sorry if I am not understanding something, but what is "yourMessage" in your example?

Comment: The message you want to send to the iframe, since your code doesn't show that.

Comment: Are you trying to send the actual iframe DOM node to a 3rd iframe? That will probably not work at all.

Comment: I am trying to send HTMLIFrameElement object to my iframe. The whole object (hoping it is possible).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach? If you read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm (the algo used by postMessage) it cleary states that you can't pass DOM nodes through `postMessage()`. So maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: I need myHTMLIFrameElement (non iframe) utilized by my jquery iframe code. Since iframe code and non-iframe code are on two different domains, I do get access denied error once the iframe code tries get non-iframe myHTMLIFrameElement. So I have been trying to figure out a way to send the HTMLIFrameElement from non-iframe to iframe code via postMessage.